# Conjugates in an alternating group

Tags: group-theory

I know that the conjugates of (1 2 3) in S_4 are all 3-cycles in S_4, but I have read that the conjugates of the same cycle in A_4 are not all 3-cycles in A_4. How do I know which elements are conjugates of (1 2 3) in A_4?

Answer (score 1):

You could just brute-force it and conjugate with all elements in $A_4$.

If you want to give it a little bit more thought before you start computing:

The centralizer has at least order $3$, thus the conjugacy class has at most $4$ elements, thus you search for the three other elements other than $(123)$ itself. They are obtained by conjugation with $(14)(23), (24)(13), (34)(12)$ respectively, since conjugation by these three obviously give distinct elements.